# Android E(ICS / 4.0) emulator inside Virtual Machine (VMWare)

Tags: android, android-emulator, memory-management, android-virtual-device

I've been trying to run the AVD for Android r14 inside a Virtual Machine using VMWare with almost no success. The r11-r13 versions were painful in the extreme but with r14, it has finally reached the unusable stage.

Clearly the best option is not to run inside a VM but this is being forced upon me by requirements.

I've tried running VMWare guests of Windows 7 (32 & 64) and Ubuntu 11.10 (32 bit) which all give pretty much the same results: either the emulator does not start at all (freezes) or starts after about 30 minutes but will then never start again. The host is Windows XP 64.

I've tried allocating between 800 and 1024MB of RAM to the emulator, the guest VM's all have 2GB allocated to them and the host has 8GB of RAM. The logcat output seems to indicate a huge number of Garbage collection events yet the emulator process appears to be only using a fraction of the allocated memory (On the rare occasions it starts, the process does then take the amount of memory allocated to the device). The guest OS's are nowhere near using their full memory allocation.

The emulator debug output shows no errors at all.

If by any chance, anyone has any ideas, please do share.

Update: I've just tried a VBox XP guest with an Ubuntu host. I get

"C:\android-sdk\tools>Failed to allocate memory: 8

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run Android_x86 in VirtualBox (Oracle WM).

To do this, create a VM (choose **Linux > Other Linux** for OS), start it,
and mount the Android_x86 ISO file as a CD-ROM.

I'm using `android-x86-2.3-RC1-eeepc.iso`.
It can be downloaded [here](http://www.android-x86.org/download).
Try it! It's easy.

Comment: Thanks Paul,Unfortunately, I need to be able to use features such as Fragments and Drag and Drop.

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, don't include taglines/signatures in your posts. Read [the FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). Thanks!

Comment: In this redaction you can use Fragments and D&D with soft-mousekey

Comment: @PavelShestakov Since you seem to have android on Vbox, would this configuration support connecting android as USB to the parent machine ? I want to try MTP protocal and I do not have an ICS device which supports MTP.